# I have a issue while run my controller in angularjs using Chrome

Tags: php, angularjs, google-chrome, object

**I am battling with this code run on crome then it has been throw the following error.but everything is working fine in firefox**

```
1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
2)Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=lens_admin&p1=Erro…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.28%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)
```

**inside my Controller:**

```
 angular.module('lens_admin.controllers', ['angularFileUpload']).
.controller('adminController', function($scope,$http,$location,$upload) {
$scope.brand_edit_submit = function(bid) {
var brand_type_editObj=new Object();
brand_type_editObj.edit_mode='brand';
brand_type_editObj.bid=bid;
brand_type_editObj.brand_type_edit=$scope.brand_type_edit;
$http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{brand_type_editObj}).  //first error focus here.am i correct to passing Object to server side..
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
alert(data);
$scope.brand_type_tables();
$scope.lens_brand_table();
$('.modal').modal('hide');
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
alert("Please Try Again..!");
});
}
});
```

i have embedded files for "angularFileUpload" module that included in my "admin.controllers".what is wrong with my code.this issue occured only in crome..any one can give me some ideas..
Thanks Advance..

Comment: `1)Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` will show a line, what line?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }             controller.js:424

Comment: $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{brand_type_editObj}).   //this is the 424 line in my controller.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error line:

```
$http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{brand_type_editObj})
```

This is because

```
{brand_type_editObj}
```

Isn't a proper object.

It needs to be

```
{ someName: brand_type_editObj }
```

Where I have introduced a key `someName`. JavaScript objects are key/value pairs. So there always needs to be a `Key` and there always needs to be a `Value`.

> 2)Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=lens_admin&p1=Erro…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.28%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

This occured because it probably couldn't find `['angularFileUpload']`. But with out seeing the main script its hard to know for sure

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code
Few errors like double "." b/w module and controller
second:- Key is not assigned to object in $http call.

```
angular.module('lens_admin.controllers', ['angularFileUpload'])
    .controller('adminController', function($scope, $http, $location, $upload) {
        $scope.brand_edit_submit = function(bid) {
            var brand_type_editObj = new Object();
            brand_type_editObj.edit_mode = 'brand';
            brand_type_editObj.bid = bid;
            brand_type_editObj.brand_type_edit = $scope.brand_type_edit;
            $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{"data":brand_type_editObj}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
                $scope.brand_type_tables();
                $scope.lens_brand_table();
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Please Try Again..!");
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why moduler error occured ..                                                       Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=lens_admin&p1=Erro…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.28%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A170)

Comment: Have you added 

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- shim is needed to support non-HTML5 FormData browsers (IE8-9)-->
<script src="angular-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
<script src="angular-file-upload.min.js"></script> 
Files

Comment: i got it bro..but this issue occurred by the first error..i made this mistake in some places.so this error has occurred.now its working fine.thanks you so much bro..

Comment: $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{data:brand_type_editObj}). in the above code passing object right.. in my previous code i didn't make objct well.like this $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{brand_type_editObj}). In server side i call this objct like this @$edit_mode = $request->brand_type_editObj->edit_mode; Now i didn't make any change here..but it's work fine..Now i have passed object like {data:brand_type_editObj} but i fetch that in server side like @$edit_mode = $request->brand_type_editObj->edit_mode; can i call like this

Comment: I didn't get you can you explain >

Comment: $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{data:brand_type_editObj}). in the above code passing object right.. in my previous code i didn't make objct well.like this $http.post("ajax/frame_list_update.php",{brand_type_editObj}). In server side i call this objct like this @$edit_mode = $request->brand_type_editObj->edit_mode; Now i didn't make any change here..but it's work fine..Now i have passed object like {data:brand_type_editObj} but i fetch that in server side like @$edit_mode = $request->brand_type_editObj->edit_mode; can i call like this

Comment: No,You should fetch "data" object there

Comment: sorry bro..i have some cookie pbm..ya you are correct..thanks again